# How to identify and remove a looping sound?

Tags: audio, bugs

I have a Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.2 (not rooted, but with developer options enabled), and it keeps developing a stuck looping sound (I guess part of a notification sound, looping approximately every second). It survives shutdown / restart, and I've been through killing processes and services, and apparently at random at some point after killing everything, it **sometimes** seems to stop (sometimes it keeps going no matter how many you kill)...

...but it keeps coming back. I'm at the 4th or 5th time in 24 hours where I think it is fixed, only to find it bleeping away later. Obviously this makes it hard to leave the volume on!

So: any ideas on identifying the offender? Maybe some tool that can display the sound buffers by originating process? Or just flush them...

Note: it also survives a reboot into safe mode, continuing to play in a loop while in safe mode.

Comment: Do you have few enough notification-enabled accounts that you could disable notification for a bunch of them at a time until you found the culprit? Not ideal, I realize...

Comment: @Jon to be clear: do you mean the "show norifications" box on an app-by-app basis?

Comment: Yes. I realize that's somewhat painful...

Comment: @Jon not a problem: I can try that - while investigating there's only a handful of things I will have been using...

Comment: @Jon all apps notification-disabled; all processes/services killed; rebooted - still beeping at me. This next might sound crazy, but I noticed the sound "stalled" (but continued) when tilting the phone. I shook the phone (gently-ish) and now the sound has stopped. Only thing I did was shake. Confused.

Comment: Hmm. The fact that the beeping survives a reboot is pretty concerning, to be honest. I don't know enough about Android to give more than "onlooker suggestions" but it does sound grim. Have you tried a *hard* reboot (shutdown, wait a bit and then turn on) rather than just a soft reboot?

Comment: @Jon yup; turned it off hard overnight etc

Comment: @Jon more info: unrelated to notification. Starts when using power button to turn screen off, then back on. I'm wondering if "thy 'phone is knackered" is the prognosis

Comment: @Jon and after it starts, shaking the phone is definitely the thing that makes it stop. I wonder if it is something like a dodgy usb / audio cable detection switch

Comment: @Jon and just to prove me wrong, it also just started and stopped with neither power button nor shaking. Just at random. All apps still notification-disabled.

Comment: Your prognosis sounds unfortunate but correct to me - definitely sounds hardwarish rather than software :(

Comment: From a purely diagnostic perspective, the only other worthwhile test I can think of would be completely wiping the device (system, data, and cache) and re-flashing it with factory images. If your issue persists through that, I'd say it's almost certainly a hardware problem. You'd lose all of your data, in the process, though.

Comment: @eldarerathis yeah, that's towards the "last things to try" end of the list, but it is on there. For now I'm trying a deep clean and air-can. So far, so good.

Comment: You mentioned that it stops for a short while when you kill many apps. Try killing one by one and see which one it is that way.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what could cause this problem. 
Maybe you're able to tell what happened before the sound started? Could be a hint to address the issue.

I would recommend start with uninstalling any unecessary apps and going through every app that is/was ever generating notifications for you. Check their internal settings (if there are any) and also check notification settings in app manager.

If you're using developer mode I suppose you can also try to turn it off, just in case.

If it's reacting on shake in a weird way I'd also recommend to run all possible updates, alternatively reinstall apps or in the worst case: reinstall the system. Can't tell more about what could cause the bug.